# Upload image Selenium Webdriver Python - Unable upload image => Error: "Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":""

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, file-upload

I encountered an image upload problem on Selenium webdriver in Python, I inspected the HTML and used Full Xpath to locate the element but it didn't work.
I still get this error *selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IaVu0.png)/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/div[3]/div"}*

This is my code:

```
#step 2 upload photo
upload_photo = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/div[3]/div')
upload_photo.send_keys("/Users/Documents/2020//CASINO/668X593.png")
time.sleep(2)
```

And this is the HTML snipet:

```
    <div class="ve-Fc-Ye-Qd-Jo">Drag photos and videos here</div>
    <div class="ve-Fc-Ye-Qd-Io">Or, if you prefer...</div>
    <div id=":f"><div role="button" class="a-b-c d-u d-u-F" tabindex="0" style="user-select: none;">Select photos and videos from your computer
    </div>
</div>
```

[Screnshot of interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IaVu0.png)

Comment: share the html dom so we can help writing you a proper xpath

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.To get the div inside the div id=':f'.

```
upload_photo = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*div[@id=':f']/div")
upload_photo.send_keys("/Users/Documents/2020/CASINO/668X593.png")
```

Comment: I've just tryed, i've got this error again: selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //*div[@id=':f']/div because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//*div[@id=':f']/div' is not a valid XPath expression.

Answer (score 0):

Try to find element by id:

```
upload_photo = driver.find_element_by_id(":f")
```

You can also use waits to solve following difficult : if an element is not yet present in the DOM.

See more here about it:

[https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#:~:text=Selenium%20Webdriver%20provides%20two%20types,trying%20to%20locate%20an%20element](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#:%7E:text=Selenium%20Webdriver%20provides%20two%20types,trying%20to%20locate%20an%20element).